# iOS : Gradient semi transparent image overlay on

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I need to make my scrollview to be transparent at top and bottom while the underneath text view could be scrolled like shown below.
[image]

I made one .png image in photoshop with gradient (black on top) and transparency at bottom.
When I added the image onto the Image view that is atop the scorllview, and run it on the simulator, the whole image is pure black and transparency gone.

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Set your imageView's background color to clear.

Also, wouldn't the image you need be white on bottom and transparent on top, rather than black on top and transparent on bottom?

Comment: Hi. I wanted to make it with black. I got it solved. I have been saving that as JPG. My mistake. :D

Answer (score 0):

My mistake... I have saved the image as JPG. not PNG.  PNG is working properly. Thanks!